# iOS How to use YouTube iFrame API Events inside WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

I want to autoplay a YouTube video or to console log the current the current time of the video but nothing seems to be working. I need to know where do I put this Events and how to put a callback on them?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.ytPlayer.delegate = self
    self.ytPlayer.load(withVideoId: "0UjHDYppsjU", playerVars: playerVars)
}

func playerViewDidBecomeReady(_ playerView: WKYTPlayerView) {
    playerView.playVideo();
}

func playerView(_ playerView: WKYTPlayerView, didPlayTime playTime: Float, time d: TimeInterval) {
    print("time \(playTime)")
    self.progressBar.progress = self.progressBar.progress + (playTime)
}

func getDuration(_ playerView: WKYTPlayerView, duration d: TimeInterval) {
    print("duration \(d)")
}
```

Comment: why do you say WKWebView?

Comment: Because video is loaded inside a WKWebView @AndreaMugnaini

Comment: from your code looks like your are using `YTPlayerView` (which is mounted on a `UIWebView`), am I wrong?

Comment: yes but it is mounted inside a WKWebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable the autoplay you may implement the delegate `WKYTPlayerViewDelegate`, especially the function `playerViewDidBecomeReady`. A simple example of usage might be:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKYTPlayerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var ytPlayer: WKYTPlayerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var playerVars: [String:Any] = [
            "autoplay": 1,
            "playsinline" : 1,
            "enablejsapi": 1,
            "wmode": "transparent",
            "controls": 0,
            "showinfo": 0,
            "rel": 0,
            "modestbranding": 1,
            "iv_load_policy": 3 //annotations
        ]
        self.ytPlayer.delegate = self
        self.ytPlayer.load(withVideoId: "DfWI-yV7TUY", playerVars: playerVars)
    }

    func playerViewDidBecomeReady(_ playerView: WKYTPlayerView) {
        playerView.playVideo()

        playerView.getDuration { (timeInterval, error) in
            print("duration: \(timeInterval)")
        }
    }

    func playerView(_ playerView: WKYTPlayerView, didPlayTime playTime: Float) {
        print("time \(playTime)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error here: ` self.ytPlayer.delegate = self`


Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

`self.ytPlayer = WKYTPlayerView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.ytPlayer.delegate = self`

Comment: ok, are you using this library: https://github.com/hmhv/YoutubePlayer-in-WKWebView ?

Comment: exactly! I using that @Andrea

Comment: thanks, Please check my updated question, I updated it as you suggested but with WKWebView instead

`self.ytPlayer.delegate = self` this gives the error but in runtime not on build.

Comment: I have exactly the same code but `self.ytPlayer.delegate = self` throws a runtime error. `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: But why it quits and then highlights this line `self.ytPlayer.delegate = self` ?

Comment: Thanks I will check that. I have the exact code as you!!! Can you check mine please! it is also on github: 
https://gitlab.com/rexhin/ios-kida.git

Comment: found why, just a second and I give you the solution

Comment: It is, But I have two more problems now. 
First it goes full screen and also     `func onStateChange(_ playerView: WKYTPlayerView) {
        print("time");
        print(playerView.getCurrentTime());
    }` doesn't print anything. I want this to update a progress bar. Can you pull again from my github please?

Comment: Damm man you are awesome!! thanks a lot really. But How to you do it man? I have been using the iFrame API for years in JS but I want to know how to convert these functions to SWIFT,  I mean how do you add the params and stuff?

Comment: One last thing please. How Do I get the video duration.

I really tried I went through the whole  WKYTPlayerView.m file but I can not print it, check my updated question please.